# Unable to delete recup_dir.1 folder

Tags: delete

A folder was created when I used a utility to recover pictures from a cd card that I deleted by mistake.

Now I can't delete it or move it. I am told I am not the owner of it even when I am logged on as root.

How can I delete the `recup_dir.1` folder from my machine?

Answer (score 2):

I found this on launchpad and it answered my question. Thanks for the hilp.

I am not completely sure where these files are coming from, but http://www.aypcservices.com/?p=5525 (middle part of the page) indicates that they might be reconstructed picture files from the PhotoRec program (part of the testdisk package).

It seems they have been created in a way that they are owend by 'root', and you do not have access rights to look at them. To overcome that restriction you can do the following:

Open a terminal (Applications -> Accessories -> Terminal, or press ALT+F2, or press Ctrl+Alt+T) and in the window that opens enter "gksudo nautilus" (without the quotes). This will ask for your password and open a new file browser window with access rights as if logged in as root.

Now you should be able to browse all files.

Please use extreme caution when using this technique, because in that window the restrictions imposed on a 'normal user' (like: no rights to delete important system files) are temporarily overridden.

Comment: If you found an answer, you should mark it as Answer. See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: I had to change **gksudo nautilus** to **sudo nemo** on my Mint 20 system. I got a whole stream of errors (to do with file sharing) in the terminal itself, but it opened a GUI file explorer window within which I had no problem deleting these unwanted files created by an abortive earlier attempt to recover accidentally-deleted files using "testdisk + photorec" (total waste of time that attempted file recovery was).

Answer (score 1):

When logged in as root open up a terminal, the command you should use is `rm -rf ./recup_dir.1`

Comment: Copied rm -rf ./recup_dir.1 from your post and entered it into a terminal and this was the output.

Comment: Sorry about that. <g> bob@bob-HP:~$ rm -rf ./recup_dir.1
The folder is still locked and I can not delete it.

Answer (score 0):

sudo rm -rf recup_dir*    This command will delete all dir begin with recup.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me, taken from [this page](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_FAQ):

"You may need to take ownership of the folders: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308421
   Change the owner of the files, example:

```
sudo chown -R username recup_dir
```

or

```
sudo chown -R username /home/username/testdisk-6.14/recup_dir
```

(When asked for the password, use the password from your user session to
validate the sudo command)"

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rm -r /home/elrafie/recup_dir.1
sudo rm -r /home/elrafie/recup_dir.2
```

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo rm -r /home/elrafie/recup_dir.*
```